# Android BrowseFragment scroll speed

Tags: android, memory-management

I am experimenting with Android's [BrowseFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/BrowseFragment.html) sample app in an Amazon Fire TV app.  I'm running into memory issues while horizontally scrolling through the rows (both in the BrowseFragment itself and the [DetailsFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/DetailsFragment.html) on the related video row).

```
Out of memory on a 2073616-byte allocation.
can't open /data/misc/app_oom.hprof: Permission denied
error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

When you hold down the left or right remote button, the scrolling is extremely fast and I think too many images are trying to load at once.  I can reproduce this issue by entering the details screen and continuously scrolling to the right on the related video row.  Is there a way to slow down the scrolling speed on the BrowseFragment?  Thanks.